# Creating an Association List in Scheme for Memoization

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to memoize the factorial function in Scheme using an association list. However, I am having trouble getting the memoization process to work properly. I have initialized the global empty association list by

```
(define al '()) ; association list
```

Next, I defined the factorial function in Scheme:

```
(define (fac n)
 (cond ((<= n 1) 1)
 (else (* n (fac (- n 1))))))
```

I then broke the memoization process into three parts; a bind function, a lookup function and the factorial memoization function.

The `lookup` function checks to see if the association list already contains the value of the particular factorial operation. The code is as follows:

```
(define (lookup k al)  ;; lookup function
  (cond
    ((null? al) #f)
    ((equal? k (caar al)) (cadr (car al))) 
    (else (lookup k (cdr al)))))
```

The `bind` function will kick in when the value of the factorial function isn't already in the association list:

```
(define (bind k v al)  ;; bind function
    (cond 
        ((null? al) (set! al (list (list k v))))
        (else (set! al (cons (list k v) al)))) v)
```

Finally, the `lookup` and `bind` functions were utilized in the `fac_mem` function:

```
(define (fac_mem n)  ;; fac_mem function
  (cond
    ((equal? (lookup n al) #f) (set! al (bind n (fac n) al)))
    (else (begin
            (display "memoization hit \n")
            (lookup n al)))))
```

The intention of the above was to have the `fac_mem` function take a value, `n`, check to see if the factorial of `n` already exists in the association list `al` (from being computed previously) via the `lookup` function, and, if it doesn't exist in the association list, compute the factorial of `n` and insert it into the association list via the `bind` function. If the factorial of `n` does exist in the association list, the program will simply return the value via the association list rather than computing it again.

However, whenever I run `fac_mem`, the program seems to prompt for a second argument, as if the function is curried. I am not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say in what way your program "seems to" prompt for an argument, so I can't address that (I just get nothing).
I'll address some other issues instead.

The Scheme standard doesn't specify whether `set!` returns a meaningful value or not, so strange things can happen if you  rely on it.

First, note that `(list (list k v))` is the same as `(cons (list k v) '())`, so both branches of `bind` do the same thing.

I would personally prefer a table of pairs rather than lists, since there is exactly one value for each key.

One major issue is that `bind` modifies its argument `al`, which is not the same variable as the global `al`.
This means that you will never find anything in the table.

```
> (bind 12 "hello" al)
"hello"
> (lookup 12)
#f
> al
'()
```

(It's a very good idea to test each function in isolation before you start putting them together.)

You need to `set!` the global:

```
(define (bind k v)
  (set! al (cons (cons k v) al))
  v)
```

you can change `lookup` to use the global while you're at it:

```
(define (lookup k)
  (cond
    ((null? al) #f)
    ((equal? k (car (car al))) (cdr (car al))) 
    (else (lookup k (cdr al)))))

> (bind 12 "hello")
"hello"
> (lookup 12)
"hello"
> al
'((12 . "hello"))
```

In `fac_mem`, `bind` has already updated the table, so you don't need to do it again.
Using a `let` to avoid a double lookup, `fac_mem` becomes this:

```
(define (fac_mem n)
    (let ((memo (lookup n)))
          (if memo
              memo
              (bind n (fac n)))))
```

or even

```
(define (fac_mem n)
  (or (lookup n)
      (bind n (fac n))))
```

(`or` return the first argument that's not `#f`.)

Now you have another problem:

```
> (fac_mem 5)
120
> al
'((5 . 120))
```

The memoization doesn't actually memoize very much.

Fixing this left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this for a different purpose. You might find it useful. The original version, with additional commentary, is available [here](https://programmingpraxis.com/2017/05/19/just-showing-off/).

Let’s consider a simple program to calculate the *n*<sup>th</sup> fibonacci number. Mathematically, the definition is that the *n*<sup>th</sup> fibonacci number is the sum of the *n*-1<sup>th</sup> fibonacci number and the *n*-2<sup>th</sup> fibonacci number, with the first two fibonacci numbers being 1 and 1. That translates directly to Scheme like this:

```
(define (fib n)
  (if (< n 2) 1
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

Timing the calculation shows that it quickly grows slow as *n* grows large, which makes sense because the algorithm takes exponential time to repeatedly recalculate all the smaller fibonacci numbers:

```
> (time (fib 40))
(time (fib 40))
    no collections
    15069 ms elapsed cpu time
    15064 ms elapsed real time
    0 bytes allocated
165580141
```

Fifteen seconds is a long time to calculate a small number.

It is easy to write a Scheme macro that memoizes, or caches, the results of the subproblems inherent in the fibonacci calculation. Here’s the macro:

```
(define-syntax define-memoized
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((define-memoized (f arg ...) body ...)
      (define f
        (let ((cache (list)))
          (lambda (arg ...)
            (cond ((assoc `(,arg ...) cache) => cdr)
            (else (let ((val (begin body ...)))
                    (set! cache (cons (cons `(,arg ...) val) cache))
                    val)))))))))
```

We’ll explain that in a moment. But first let’s look at how to write the fibonacci function using that macro:

```
(define-memoized (fib n)
  (if (< n 2) 1
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

That is, of course, exactly the same as the earlier fibonacci function, except that we used `define-memoized` instead of simple `define` to write the function. But look at what a difference the memoization makes:

```
> (time (fib 40))
(time (fib 40))
    no collections
    0 ms elapsed cpu time
    0 ms elapsed real time
    5456 bytes allocated
165580141
```

We’ve gone from fifteen seconds to zero without doing any work, which is astonishing! Even calculating a number like (fib 4000) doesn’t cause any trauma:

```
> (time (fib 4000))
(time (fib 4000))
    no collections
    141 ms elapsed cpu time
    144 ms elapsed real time
    1364296 bytes allocated
64574884490948173531376949015369595644413900640151342708407577598177210359034088
91444947780728724174376074152378381889749922700974218315248201906276355079874370
42751068564702163075936230573885067767672020696704775060888952943005092911660239
47866841763853953813982281703936665369922709095308006821399524780721049955829191
40702994362208777929645917401261014865952038117045259114133194933608057714170864
57836066360819419152173551158109939739457834939838445927496726613615480616157565
95818944317619922097369917676974058206341892088144549337974422952140132621568340
70101627342272782776272615306630309305298205175744474242803310752241946621965578
04131017595052316172225782924860810023912187851892996757577669202694023487336446
62725774717740924068828300186439425921761082545463164628807702653752619616157324
434040342057336683279284098590801501
```

How does it work? The high-level explanation is that the macro modifies `fib` to store internally, in *cache*, the result of previous function calls with the same parameters, and return them directly instead of recalculating them. Thus, when `(fib 40)` requires the result of `(fib 39)` and `(fib 38)`, the results are already available and don’t need to be recomputed. The *cache* data structure is known in Scheme parlance as an a-list (an association list), meaning it is a linked list of key/value pairs where the key is *n* and the value is `(fib n)`. Function `assoc` looks up the key in the *cache*, `` `(,arg ...) `` is a quasi-quotation that expands the arguments to the function (`fib` takes only one argument, but the macro admits functions that take more than one). The `=>` symbol is syntax that passes the result of a `cond` predicate to its consequent, and `cdr` is a function that extracts the value from the key/value pair. The `else` clause of the `cond` calculates a never-before-seen value in the `let` expression, then updates the *cache* with `set!` and returns the newly-computed value.